# When i run npm start after creating React app, it's giving me this error:

Tags: reactjs, caching, terminal, compiler-errors, create-react-app

Compiled with problems: × ERROR [eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/samarbekovachynara/Desktop/my-app/node_modules/.cache'

This is how it looks on Terminal:

Failed to compile.

[eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/samarbekovachynara/Desktop/my-app/node_modules/.cache'
ERROR in [eslint] EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/samarbekovachynara/Desktop/my-app/node_modules/.cache'

webpack compiled with 1 error

I tried to clean the npm cache, before that i was having some problems with creating react app, it was showing me this error: Error: EACCES: permission denied, access '/usr/local/lib/node_modules'.
I somehow fixed the problem and afterwards another problem appeared.

Comment: That's permission errors. Not sure what OS you are using and from where/how you are running your commands, but the user running `npm start` does not have write previleges in your directory. Did you create it with root and now trying to use it with your normal user maybe?

Comment: My OS is MacOS Monterey(v-12) with M1, i was running my commands on terminal. I'm a beginner in React, i just wanted create react app, but it start giving me the errors after i typed npx create-react-app, i also tried to add sudo in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I was facing this same error on running the `npm start` command on terminal on my Mac

I was able to fix this error by adding `sudo` before the `npm start` command :-

```
sudo npm start
```

I had to run the `sudo npm start` command only once, after that, I was able to run the `npm start` command without any errors